# Roll up summary field max value in database

Tags: apex, custom-field, data-export, roll-up-summary, database

I want to export Roll up summary fields to external system. What should be database column length. Should i use int, bigint or any other data type. I was just doing testing in my org and roll up summary value was `10,128,999,999,999,989,887.00`. which is bigger than max length allowed in salesforce i.e 18 digits. [image]

I think these values might not be reached in real use case, but just wanted to make sure what maximum value a roll-up summary can store. If there is any salesforce documentation on this that will help also. Thanks.